# Double integration in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I get to know about integra12() can do the double calculation but I don't know the syntax. 
I tried q = integral2(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax). but I don't know how to define function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the documentation? There are a lot of examples on the [mathworks page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html).

```
fun = @(x,y) x.^2 + y.^2;

xmin = 0; xmax = 5;
ymin = -5; ymax = 0;

q = integral2(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax); % q = 4.166666666667348e+02
```